# Проблема с драйверами видео после установки Debian 11

Tags: linux, debian, драйвер

На работе выдали новое железо, на него поставил последний Debian 11.

Все стало нормально, только разрешение экрана никак не могу выставить более чем 1024*768 (стоит по-умолчанию и оно единственное).

Не настолько глубоко разбираюсь в нюансах видеодрайверов в Дебиане, чтобы решить данную проблему самостоятельно.

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему с видео-драверами.

```
    root@debian:~# lspci
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4c43 (rev 01)
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 4c8a (rev 04)
    00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4c09 (rev 01)
    00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 43ed (rev 11)
    00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 43ef (rev 11)
    00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 43e8 (rev 11)
    00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 43e0 (rev 11)
    00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 43d2 (rev 11)
    00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 43bc (rev 11)
    00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 43bf (rev 11)
    00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 43b0 (rev 11)
    00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4387 (rev 11)
    00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 43c8 (rev 11)
    00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 43a3 (rev 11)
    00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 43a4 (rev 11)
    01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809
    03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 05)
    root@debian:~#
```

```
    root@debian:~# aptitude search intel
p   firmware-intel-sound            - Binary firmware for Intel sound DSPs      
p   firmware-intelwimax             - Binary firmware for Intel WiMAX Connection
p   golang-github-intel-tfortools-d - template scripting support to go programs
p   intel-cmt-cat                   - Intel cache monitoring and allocation tech
p   intel-gpu-tools                 - tools for debugging the Intel graphics dri
p   intel-hdcp                      - Intel unified HDCP implementation -- users
i A intel-media-va-driver           - VAAPI driver for the Intel GEN8+ Graphics
p   intel-media-va-driver-non-free  - VAAPI driver for the Intel GEN8+ Graphics
p   intel-microcode                 - Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPU
p   intel-mkl                       - Intel® Math Kernel Library (Intel® MKL)  
p   intel-mkl-cluster               - Intel® Math Kernel Library (Intel® MKL) (C
p   intel-mkl-doc                   - Intel® Math Kernel Library (Intel® MKL) (D
p   intel-mkl-full                  - Intel® Math Kernel Library (Intel® MKL) (F
p   intel-opencl-icd                - Intel graphics compute runtime for OpenCL
v   intel-rng-tools                 -                                          
p   intel2gas                       - converter from NASM assembly language to G
i A libdrm-intel1                   - программный интерфейс к дополнительным фун
p   libintellij-annotations-java    - transitional package for libjetbrains-anno
p   libintellij-annotations-java-do - transitional package for libjetbrains-anno
p   libintellij-java-compatibility- - Classes from JDK8 excluded from JDK9      
p   libintelrdfpmath-dev            - Intel Decimal Floating-Point Math Library
p   libjdom2-intellij-java          - lightweight and fast XML DOM library (Inte
p   libjdom2-intellij-java-doc      - documentation for IntelliJ version of JDOM
p   libmkl-blacs-intelmpi-ilp64     - Intel® MKL : ILP64 BLACS routines for Inte
p   libmkl-blacs-intelmpi-lp64      - Intel® MKL : LP64 BLACS routines for Intel
p   libmkl-intel-ilp64              - Intel® MKL: ILP64 interface library for th
p   libmkl-intel-lp64               - Intel® MKL: LP64 interface library for the
p   libmkl-intel-thread             - Intel® MKL: OpenMP threading library for t
p   libtrove-intellij-java          - high performance collections for java    
p   python3-intelhex                - Python support for Intel HEX (Python3)    
i A xserver-xorg-video-intel        - X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display
```

```
    root@debian:~# lsmod
    Module                  Size  Used by
    snd_hda_codec_hdmi     73728  0
    snd_hda_codec_realtek   155648  1
    snd_hda_codec_generic    98304  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
    hid_logitech_hidpp     49152  0
    joydev                 28672  0
    hid_logitech_dj        28672  0
    hid_generic            16384  0
    usbhid                 65536  1 hid_logitech_dj
    hid                   147456  4 usbhid,hid_generic,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
    intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
    intel_rapl_common      28672  1 intel_rapl_msr
    x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
    intel_powerclamp       20480  0
    coretemp               20480  0
    kvm_intel             327680  0
    snd_sof_pci            24576  0
    snd_sof_intel_byt      24576  1 snd_sof_pci
    snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
    snd_sof_intel_hda_common   102400  1 snd_sof_pci
    kvm                   921600  1 kvm_intel
    snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt
    snd_sof               139264  4 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc
    snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
    snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
    snd_hda_ext_core       36864  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
    snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    45056  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
    snd_soc_acpi           16384  3 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt
    ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_sof
    snd_hda_intel          57344  2
    snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
    soundwire_intel        45056  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_intel_dspcfg
    soundwire_generic_allocation    16384  1 soundwire_intel
    nls_ascii              16384  1
    mei_hdcp               24576  0
    snd_soc_core          315392  4 soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
    nls_cp437              20480  1
    irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
    vfat                   20480  1
    snd_compress           32768  1 snd_soc_core
    fat                    86016  1 vfat
    soundwire_cadence      36864  1 soundwire_intel
    snd_hda_codec         172032  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
    ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
    snd_hda_core          110592  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
    snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
    soundwire_bus          90112  3 soundwire_intel,soundwire_generic_allocation,soundwire_cadence
    eeepc_wmi              16384  0
    asus_wmi               45056  1 eeepc_wmi
    battery                20480  1 asus_wmi
    snd_pcm               135168  9 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core
    aesni_intel           368640  0
    snd_timer              49152  1 snd_pcm
    sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
    iTCO_wdt               16384  0
    libaes                 16384  1 aesni_intel
    crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
    cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
    glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
    snd                   110592  14 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
    intel_pmc_bxt          16384  1 iTCO_wdt
    rfkill                 28672  2 asus_wmi
    iTCO_vendor_support    16384  1 iTCO_wdt
    pcspkr                 16384  0
    mei_me                 45056  1
    soundcore              16384  1 snd
    watchdog               28672  1 iTCO_wdt
    efi_pstore             16384  0
    wmi_bmof               16384  0
    ee1004                 20480  0
    mei                   139264  3 mei_hdcp,mei_me
    tpm_crb                20480  0
    tpm_tis                16384  0
    tpm_tis_core           28672  1 tpm_tis
    tpm                    73728  3 tpm_tis,tpm_crb,tpm_tis_core
    evdev                  28672  18
    rng_core               16384  1 tpm
    intel_pmc_core         45056  0
    acpi_pad              184320  0
    acpi_tad               20480  0
    parport_pc             40960  0
    ppdev                  24576  0
    lp                     20480  0
    parport                69632  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
    fuse                  167936  1
    configfs               57344  1
    efivarfs               16384  1
    ip_tables              32768  0
    x_tables               53248  1 ip_tables
    autofs4                53248  2
    ext4                  921600  1
    crc16                  16384  1 ext4
    mbcache                16384  1 ext4
    jbd2                  151552  1 ext4
    crc32c_generic         16384  0
    i915                 2715648  0
    ahci                   40960  0
    libahci                45056  1 ahci
    xhci_pci               20480  0
    xhci_hcd              303104  1 xhci_pci
    libata                290816  2 libahci,ahci
    i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
    drm_kms_helper        278528  1 i915
    r8169                 102400  0
    cec                    61440  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
    usbcore               323584  3 xhci_hcd,usbhid,xhci_pci
    drm                   618496  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
    scsi_mod              262144  1 libata
    realtek                24576  1
    nvme                   49152  3
    mdio_devres            16384  1 r8169
    libphy                151552  3 r8169,mdio_devres,realtek
    nvme_core             126976  5 nvme
    crc32_pclmul           16384  0
    crc32c_intel           24576  2
    i2c_i801               32768  0
    t10_pi                 16384  1 nvme_core
    intel_lpss_pci         24576  0
    crc_t10dif             20480  1 t10_pi
    i2c_smbus              20480  1 i2c_i801
    intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
    crct10dif_generic      16384  0
    usb_common             16384  2 xhci_hcd,usbcore
    idma64                 20480  0
    crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
    crct10dif_common       16384  3 crct10dif_generic,crc_t10dif,crct10dif_pclmul
    wmi                    36864  2 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof
    fan                    20480  0
    video                  53248  2 asus_wmi,i915
    button                 24576  0
    root@debian:~#
```

```
root@debian:~# glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"
Error: unable to open display

root@debian:~# lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 4c8a (rev 04)
DeviceName: Onboard - Video
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
Kernel modules: i915
root@debian:~#

root@debian:~# update-pciids
--2022-03-31 13:45:53--  https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/v2.2/pci.ids.bz2
Распознаётся pci-ids.ucw.cz (pci-ids.ucw.cz)… 46.255.230.98, 2a00:da80:fff0:2::2
Подключение к pci-ids.ucw.cz (pci-ids.ucw.cz)|46.255.230.98|:443... соединение установлено.
HTTP-запрос отправлен. Ожидание ответа… 200 OK
Длина: 282492 (276K) [application/x-bzip2]
Сохранение в: «/usr/share/misc/pci.ids.new»

/usr/share/misc/pci 100%[===================>] 275,87K  1,79MB/s    за 0,2s    

2022-03-31 13:45:53 (1,79 MB/s) - «/usr/share/misc/pci.ids.new» сохранён [282492/282492]

Done.
root@debian:~#
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135190/discussion-on-question-by--------deb).

Answer (score 0):

Создайте конфигурационный файл /etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf со следующим содержанием: options i915 force_probe=4c8a. Потом удалите пакет xserver-xorg-video-intel и перезагрузите систему.